# Can I hire my wife to max out another roth 401k?

Tags: united-states, investing, retirement-plan, roth-401k

I own my own company. I am maxing out my roth 401k with a match of 4%. Can hire my wife and pay her just enough to max out another roth 401k?

Comment: You should talk to your accountant.  Not the right subject for internet advice.  However, it sounds reasonable provided adherence with plan rules.

Comment: She probably has to actually work for her pay and you can't just pay her for nothing.  I asked a similar question not too long ago: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/81311/adding-spouse-to-single-member-llc-to-reduce-taxes

Comment: How many employees do you have? Do you know that a solo 401 has a limit far higher than $18K?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the *real* answer to your question, but assuming she is homemaker or unemployed, you *can* open a [Spousal IRA](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/retirement/03/021903.asp) for her with the same contribution limits, *e.g.* $5,500 in 2017. This would be a lot easier than possibly committing tax fraud.  I was able to do this for my wife a few years ago with an online investment company.

Comment: Just a guess, but it seems likely that OP makes too much money for a spousal Roth IRA, or to deduct the traditional IRA.

Comment: I did not know there was a limit. It seems to be [$186K](https://www.fool.com/retirement/2016/11/05/ira-income-limits-for-2016-and-2017.aspx) for 2017; a problem I have not been blessed with.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco - at that level, no IRA, AMT kicks in, no Rental Real Estate deductions for passive investors. It's a nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

Legitimate periodicals have written over the years how business owners can shift income to family members. To a spouse to do exactly what you are looking for, and to children, whose earned income is taxed at their rate.

As long as the work is documented and reasonable, e.g. I couldn't pay my 10 year old $50/hr to help file, your approach is sound.